# Remove horizontal bar from website without footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap frame to create a responsive website. I realized that there is a horizontal bar at the bottom of the page, which I could not get rid of. I looked up on similar answers on stackoverflow and most of them have problems with the footer. I checked mine and I have yet to set a footer and also I do not have any width of 100%. The CSS I used also did not modify the dimensions of the bootstrap elements. May I know what is wrong with my HTML code?

My stylesheet(I am using the stylesheet provided by bootstrap for carousel and a div id of section to modify the content at the bottom :

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}

#section {
  padding-left: 5%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <!--Slideshow-->
  <div class="jumbotron" style="background:transparent !important;">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="Images/Swimming.jpg" alt="1" style="width:460px; height:345px">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Swimming</h3>
            <p>Event of Swimming</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Images/Basketball.jpg" alt="2" style="width:460px; height:345px">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Basketball</h3>
            <p>Event of Basketball</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Images/Tennis.jpg" alt="3" style="width:460px; height:345px">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Tennis</h3>
            <p>Event of Tennis</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Images/Football.jpg" alt="4" width="460" height="345">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Football</h3>
            <p>Event of Football</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="Images/Baseball.jpg" alt="5" width="460" height="345">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Baseball</h3>
            <p>Event of Baseball</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
      <h3>Registration for 2018</h3>
      <div id="registration" style="font-size: 20px;">
        <p>Click <a href="#">here</a> to Register
          <br /> Click <a href="#">here</a> to Register</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
      <h3>Announcements</h3>
      <p>s to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one
        of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum
        et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in
        section 1.10.32.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4" id="section">
      <h3>Facebook Feed</h3>
      <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
        versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the picture of my website with horizontal bar:
[image: Picture of my website with Horizontal Bar]

Hope that I can learn what is wrong with this.

Comment: Remove each section then refresh. That way you will know what is/are the offending elements

Comment: @Swellar's suggestion is a good way of locating the part of the page that is too wide. One typical cause of an unwanted horizontal scroll bar is setting negative left/right margins on an element to pull it to the edge of the viewport. The margins extend beyond the screen and force a scrollbar.  This can be solved by setting overflow: hidden on the containing element.

Comment: @Jonathan Nicol Hi Sir, I tried what Mr Sweller said and removed the jumbotron and the problem still persists. Then I tried to remove the bottom section of the rows and there are no horizontal bar anymore. I checked online and they said that .row provided by bootstrap have a -15px margin that may cause it. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: I will explain your options to remove the margins in an answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typical cause of an unwanted horizontal scroll bar is setting negative left/right margins on an element to pull it to the edge of the viewport. The margins extend beyond the screen and force a scrollbar.

Bootstrap applies -15px margins to the left and right of `.row`, which is causing the horizontal scrollbar in your case.

Bootstrap's `.row` is designed to be used inside of `.container`, which has left and right padding to compensate for the negative margins. You have a containing div, but is has an `id` of "container", not a `class`, so Bootstrap is not styling it. Add the `.container` class to it:

```
<div id="container" class="container">
```

If you find `.container`'s padding undesirable, you could instead hide its overflow with a custom CSS rule:

```
#container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. So what you mean is that I should wrap my .row elements inside a .container right? I checked that there should not be a .container wrapped inside of another .container(which I used it on top of the .jumbotron). In this case, is it possible to substitute with .container-fluid?

Comment: Actually there is currently not a .container in your markup at all. The wrapping element has the id "container", not the class "container".

Possibly what you want is a .container-fluid wrapping Jumbotron and a regular .container wrapping .row.

Comment: Or possibly no wrapper at all for Jumbotron (it has padding applied already) and either a .container or .container-fluid wrapper for .row...

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that. Thank you sir, I will test it out and see which one works best for me.